# Developers cannot see their checked in code for new project on Visual Studio Online / TFS 2013

Tags: azure-devops

I created a new team project (in Visual Studio Online) , say “MyProject”.. ( I used “create a new team project”  and selected the CMMI process improvement process template). Everything remains default.  I added a user  say MyUser.
In the “code” tab
Under $/MyProject  , BuildProcessTemplates is visible. 
“MyUser”  mapped “MyUserDir” to $/MyProject, created “dir1” under   “MyUserDir” , put binaries in dir1 and checked in. Nothing ( not even “dir1”) is visible to me or other users in VSO ( in code tab ) > I was expecting “dir1” to appear at the same level where BuildProcessTemplate is. 
Do I need to configure something?
In my case the files are binaries. There is no intent to make a build of the project.  I just intend to use it as SCM (for checkin /check out and tracking of histories)

Comment: By default Visual Studio will ignore binaries in the Add window and the pending changes window, unless the files were explicitly added / Included. In the Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio, are the files visible and is there any status listed?

Comment: Look on the changesets tab, did you commit/check-in the changeset?  Here is a link to a walkthrough (assuming you are using TFVC as the version control repository type vs. Git):  http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs

Comment: I downloaded power tools. From command prompt: "tf status" told that files were not checked in ( It was more than 1 GB file ) . Then I experimented with simple txt files. It worked. Thanks to  both jesse and Ed.   Problem solved!

Comment: @jessehouwing can you post your comments as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

By default Visual Studio will ignore binaries in the Add window and the pending changes window, unless the files were explicitly added / Included.

Either open the Source control explorer, click the add files and folders button and make sure the files you want to check in are not under the "Excluded" tab.

Or open the pending Changes window and look in the "Excluded Items" section. Rightclick each item you want to check in and select "Include Item".

Now try checking in again.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded power tools. From command prompt: "tf status" told that files were not checked in ( It was more than 1 GB file ) . Then I experimented with simple txt files. It worked. Thanks to both jesse and Ed. Problem solved!

This answer appeared as comment before. Posting it as answer according to @jessehouwing request.